# how to find specific pattern in array like this -> [number]?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, loops, foreach

how to find a pattern like **[number]** in an array?

i have an array similar this :

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '[1]', '[2]', '[3]');
```

how to filter an array and just hold those strings that have a specific pattern like **[a number]**?

Comment: Write you own parsing function, where you could use `typeof`, `isArray` e.t.c. when pass your own patterns (if you talk about [number], {object}, [string], [{object}])

Comment: Do you mean matching strings or determining the type of the values? There seems to be some confusion with the notation in your question. Strings should be properly quoted.

Comment: excuse me i edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the array with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter), then iterate through it:

```
$filtered_array = array_filter( $array, function( $el) { 
    return preg_match( '/^\[\d+\]$/', $el);
});
```

This is using a callback with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) to find entries that consist of a left square bracket `[`, then a number of digits `\d+`, then a right square bracket `]`.

Comment: `[]` is shortcut code for array now

Comment: @DevZer0 - Yes I'm aware, but `{}` is not a shortcut for anything, so the OP cannot mean to use `[]` to create a nested array (especially since the OP is using the more verbose `array()` syntax to begin with).

Answer (score 3):

You could try [`is_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php):

```
foreach ($array as $num) {
  if(is_array($num)) {
    echo $num . "<br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: is this an array? [1]

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian - No, it is not, especially since you updated your post to show that you meant to make each element of your array a string.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities, here are 2 of them.

```
<?php

$array = array(1, 2, 3, "{1}", "{2}", "{3}", "[1]", "[2]", "[3]");



// Method 1
foreach ($array as $num)
{
    if(preg_match("/\[\d+\]/", $num)){
        echo $num . "<br />";

    }
}
echo "<hr/>"
// Method 2
$filtered=preg_grep("/\[\d+\]/", $array);
foreach ($filtered as $num)
{
    echo $num . "<br />";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [preg_grep](http://php.net/preg-grep):

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '[1]', '[2]', '[3]');

$new_array = preg_grep('#^\[\d+(?:.\d+)?\]$#', $array);
$new_array = array_values($new_array); // re-index the array
print_r($new_array); // print the results
```

**Explaining the regex:**

- `^` : begin of string
- `\[` : match `[`
- `\d+` : match 1 digit or more
- `(?:.\d+)?` : match optionally the decimal part
- `\]` : match `]`
- `$` : end of string

Comment: Or [`preg_filter()`](http://php.net/preg-filter) if you don't want the brackets included.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? The regex matches the opening `[` followed by a single digit followed by the closing `]`.

```
foreach ($array as $num) { 
    if ( preg_match( '#\[\d\]#', $num ) ) {
       echo $num;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `$num` was `"[14]"` or `"abc[8]def"`. This wouldn't match the first, and would match the second.

Comment: It wasn't specified in the question what the strings could've been. I just used the examples given.